# Skip when error occurs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, skip

i have the following code in batch (cmd):

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s Example') do (
command
if %errorlevel%==1 (
command
SKIP
)
command
)
```

**EDIT:**
To make things more clear:
`for /f...` searches for a directory called 'Example' and loops to search for more directories than one.
the first `command` is a delete command, it deletes all files in the directory.
the `command` that happens when an error occurs, is a `echo` command which writes some info about the error to a text file.
now the hole `skip` thing; sometimes, the files can't be deleted because of `access denied` or `this file is in use by...`. Normally, what would happen if there weren't a skip thing, it would just stop the command and hang. So, what i want to do, is prevent this from happening. Alternatively, i want to use something like `skip`, so it can skip the file and continue anyways. So i think this command needs to be piped in the `delete` command.

I hope it's clear now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: calling out to dir is pretty stupid when for can walk a directory tree for you

Comment: Please explain better what you need. I tried to guess your intentions with my answer, but apparently was unsuccessful. What do you mean by "skip", then? Maybe you can provide a sample directory structure and expected behaviour of your batch script on that directory structure.

Comment: Your usage of the word 'skip' is extraordinarily ambiguous.

Comment: @YourComputerHelpZ - check out revised fupsduck. Thanks to Doc Brown's killtask suggestion I think this should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s Example') do (
  command
  if not errorlevel 1 (
    command-for-success
  ) else (
    command-for-error
  )
)
```

Comment: @Johannes -- wow, i didn't know about "||"! Looks like a neat way to write short alternatives.

Comment: this does not really what i want. i want to let for skip it, and continue. what the command does, it looks for 'example', and then deletes everything in that directory. The problem is that you can't really easy 'skip' it.

Comment: In batch scripts, you can also use `goto`.

Comment: @YourComputerHelpZ: this solution indeed skips "command-for-success" when an error occurs, executes "command-for-error" instead, and continues with the next file in 'example'. Please explain better what you think what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Create the two command files and run delex.cmd.  The files and directories that are not deleted will be logged to delex.txt.  The ones that hang, will have a minimized cmd window open that gets killed after a delay by using ping (thanks to Doc Brown's suggestion).

```
delex2.cmd
----------
@echo off
del /q %1 
if exist %1 echo %1 not deleted!>>delex.txt 
exit 

delex.cmd
---------
@echo off
if exist delex.txt del delex.txt 
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b example') do start "delextaskkill" /min delex2.cmd "%%f"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 -w 1000> nul
taskkill /fi "Windowtitle eq delextaskkill"> nul
```

Tested with:

```
\example
|   file1
|   file2
|   file3
|   file4
|   file5
|
\---example
        file1
        file2
        file3
        file4
        file5
```

Comment: I think this one can be improved to close all 'hanging' windows afterwards after a given timeout. Add a special windowtitle to the 'start' command. Use http://malektips.com/dos0017.html to simulate a "Wait" command (for example, wait for 10 seconds afterwards), and use taskkill /fi "Windowtitle eq <YourSpecialWindowtitle>" to kill all hanging windows.

Answer (score 1):

When one uses `del`, and  "access denied" or "this file is in use by..." occurs, `%errorlevel%` is 0, so testing `%errolevel%` is useless. Perhaps the following simple solution works in your case:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s Example') do (
    del %%f
    if exist %%f (
         echo "file not deleted"
    ) else (
         echo "file deleted"
    )
 )
```

Comment: but it wouldn't skip, does it?

Comment: I tried it with 3 files in a directory 'Example', one write protected and two in use, and I get 3 times "file not deleted". If this is not what you mean by 'skip', please give a better example or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you want

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s Example') do (
  command
  if not errorlevel 1 (
    command
  ) else (
    command
    goto :eof
  )
)
```

Comment: this is the same as @atzz, again, read the comments, i dont like that kind of stuff.

Comment: that was my best attempt trying to understand what you mean by "skip". Make some effort to improve your explanation, because if you don't you just cast doubt on the amount you really value a good answer. Your lack of interest on getting understood only rivals your rudeness.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more advanced than can be accomplished using just built-in cmd processing. Why not consider using the Windows Scripting Host (vbscript/jscript) or even PowerShell? Both will likely provide you the level of control you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file:

```
@echo off
REM For each directory named 'Example' ...
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s Example') do (
    REM .. enter the directory and delete all the files found there.
    pushd .
    cd %%f
    del /q *
    for /f "delims=" %%z in ('dir /b') do (
        REM Any files that still exist must have been inaccessable.  Log an error.
        echo Unable to delete file %%z > C:\logfile.txt
    )
    popd
)
```

Tested with the following directory structure:

```
folder\
|------Example\
|      |-------file1 (write-protected)
|      |-------file2
|      |-------file3
|------deeper\
       |-------Example\
               |-------file4
               |-------file5 (write-protected)
               |-------file6
```

After running the batch file, only `file1` and `file5` were left.  An "Access is denied" message was printed for each write-protected file encountered; if that gets annoying you re-direct the output of the batch file like `script.bat > NUL` to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

So after all the existing answers didn't satisfy you and you absolutely need a skip within your batch file, i will make another try:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s batch') do call :DoSomething %%f
goto end

:DoSomething
echo Here i am: %1
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :eof

echo No error occured
goto :eof

:end
endlocal
```

The trick is, that the for loop calls a sub function within the same file and gives the needed parameter to it. This new call runs in a new context and can only access the variables which are defined after the `do call :DoSomething` in the given order their.

So you have to access the variables here with `%1`, `%2`, etc. If you want to leave this context you have to make a `goto :eof` to jump to the end of the file (this marker is predefined in batch mode and should not occur within your file), what leaves the context and returns to the for loop.

After running through the whole loop we just jump to the `:end` marker, make a little clean up and are finished.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks for the file extentions you want recursively under the "dirname" directory tree and executes commandstuff.bat against that file name:

> for /r %i in (c:\dirname\*.ext) do
>   commandstuff "%i"

**Commandstuff.bat** looks like this:

> @ECHO OFF 
> del %1 
> IF (%ERRORLEVEL% ==
>   0) goto END
>   
>   :ERROR 
> Echo Error deleting %1 
>   
>   :END 
> Echo end

This would run commandstuff.bat for you to delete the files you want. When there is an error it will simply echo the file details and continue processing the next file.